# SocketIO not working correct on Windows IIS for client and server on same domain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to setup `socketIO` with `React` but I am a little bit stuck on trying to deploy it on my Windows IIS Server. On my local device I have a working example but I got problems with deploying it to the web.

I have created a project folder called `events`. Inside this folder I have added `client` and `server`. Inside my `server` folder I have created a `index.js` file with this content:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
//New imports
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

const socketIO = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000"
    }
});
app.post("/api", (req, res) => {
    socketIO.emit("sendPlatform", req.body);
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Success" });
});

// Socket.IO connection handler
socketIO.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A client connected');
  
    // Socket.IO event to receive data from the client
    socket.on('sendData', (data) => {
      console.log('Received data:', data);
      // Handle the received data here
  
      // Emit a response event to the specific client
      socket.emit('responseData', { message: 'Data received' });
    });
  
    // Socket.IO event for client disconnection
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('A client disconnected');
    });
  });
  

http.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Starting this with `node index.js` returns me correct log of `Server listening on 4000`.

In my `client` folder I have my `React` application with `App.js` looking like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {io} from 'socket.io-client'
const App= ()=> {
  const [platform, setPlatform] = useState('test');
  useEffect(()=> {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:4000')
    socket.on('connect', ()=> console.log('connected maat'))
    socket.on("sendPlatform", (platform) => {
        console.log(platform);
        setPlatform(platform.name);
    });
 },[])
 return (
   <div className="App">
     {platform}
   </div>
 )
}
export default App;
```

When starting this application with `npm start` the functionalities works fine.
But now I want to host this on my `Windows IIS` on the same domain.

For example I have created a domain `domainname` and placed the `server` and `client` folder in it and installed all the packages etc. I ran `npm run build` inside my `client` folder and set this as the path in my IIS manager but how do I move on now? I am a little bit stuck at this point.

I have changed `http://localhost:3000` to `domainname` inside my `index.js` when moving from local machine to Windows IIS

Comment: You can get started from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support#disable-websocket-when-using-socketio-on-nodejs and https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ to host the Node.js/Express part in a site. For React itself, it usually goes to another site.

Comment: You need to create a new website in IIS, choose the physical path to the client build folder, and set the appropriate binding information (such as hostname and port).

Comment: I have set the physical path to my client build folder and this correctly shows my react app on visiting the url. Inside the folder where the build files are there is a folder called `server`. How to set the correct binding information from now then?

Comment: [How to deploy React Application on IIS Server](https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-1ied)